# post bulk.json with axios elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, axios

I am trying to make bulk post with elasticsearch and axios ,
I have a problem with post request :

```
 axios.put('http://localhost:9200/indexrandom881', {'products-bulk.json'

});
```

For adding and deleting index it work :
Deleting and index

```
axios.delete('http://localhost:9200/indexrandom'+x, {
    });
```

Adding an index

```
  axios.put('http://localhost:9200/indexrandom881'+x, {

    });
```

Please do anyone has an idea.
In brief I need this command in axios form

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST http://localhost:9200/products/_bulk --data-binary "@products-bulk.json"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Joe Sorocin but that working only in node.js , I need to implement it in react, in react it shows error `fs.readfile` is not a function
the full essay is :

File : App.js

```js
function App() {
    const axios = require('axios');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const filePath = __dirname + '/national-es-bulk-index22.json';
    const indexName = 'indexrandom881';
    const url = `http://localhost:9200/${indexName}/_bulk`;
    
    fs.readFile(filePath, async (err, jsonData) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error({ err });
            return;
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post(url, jsonData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson'
            }
        });

        console.info({ data });
    });
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `post` instead of `put`. Also, you'll need to first read the file using `fs` before you pass it along to Elasticsearch with the [`application/x-ndjson` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64101208/8160318):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = __dirname + '/products-bulk.json';

const indexName = 'indexrandom881';
const url = `http://localhost:9200/${indexName}/_bulk`;

fs.readFile(filePath, async (err, jsonData) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error({ err });
        return;
    }

    const { data } = await axios.post(url, jsonData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson'
        }
    });

    console.info({ data });
});
```